# problem with texpad editor and the package answers

Tags: answers, texpad

I don’t know why the command \input don’t work in the package answers. If I use \include it’s OK but it’s not good because some things don’t work correctly. Only under TexPad editor.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because TeXpad doesn't use TeX to the best of my knowledge. It is implemented completely differently.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in texpad everything that is written during the compilation is placed in the .texpadtmp directory. Here you can find your temporary answer file. But then things get messed up if you use the include command, because the file cannot be found in the root directory.

To fix this, just write

```
\input{.texpadtmp/ans1}
```

instead of

```
\input{ans1}
```